# React Nuka slider where to put decorator ?

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am new to react and trying to change carousel's arrow image. The document said I can change prev, next icon with decorator. However, I do not know where to use it.

```
 var Decorators = [{
  component: React.createClass({
    render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <i className="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-3x"
                onClick={this.props.previousSlide} aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
      )
    }
  }),
  position: 'CenterLeft',
  style: {
    padding: 20
  }
}];
```

Does anybody have example code for this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a "decorators" property on the carousel component; set it to the custom Decorators array you created like this:

```
<Carousel decorators={Decorators}>...</Carousel>
```

Full example

```
'use strict';

    var React = require('react');

    var Carousel = require('nuka-carousel');

    const App = React.createClass({
      mixins: [Carousel.ControllerMixin],
      render() {

     var Decorators = [{
      component: React.createClass({
        render() {
          return (
             <div>
                <i className="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-3x"
                    onClick={this.props.previousSlide} aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
          )
        }
      }),
      position: 'CenterLeft',
      style: {
        padding: 20
      }
    }];
        return (
          <Carousel decorators={Decorators}>
            <div>Slide 1</div>
            <div>Slide 2</div>
            <div>Slide 3</div>
          </Carousel>
        )
      }
    });

    module.exports = App;
```